# SSHD ST1000LM014-1EJ1 keeps spinning up and down when my laptop is on battery mode and screen is off

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, battery

So this is the main problem as described in the title. I am wondering if anybody found a solution to this cause that could eventually, kill my hard-disk from all those spins-ups and downs. I have searched the web and found that disabling the `Link State Power Management` under `PCI Express` from the `Power Options` could make this go away. Maybe for some this works but for me unfortunately it isn't.
What does work for me is choosing `Never` turn off the screen when system going idle, on each power scheme when my laptop is unplugged. When it's plugged in, everything is fine, even choosing to turn off my screen after some time.

Laptop model: Aspire V3-571G, even though I don't think this matters.

OS: Windows 10 Professional X64, with legit key of course.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar situation with ST2000LX001 and Windows 7 except I get it when plugged in.